# GetResponse() error due to 'WebRequest'

Tags: c#, webrequest, getresponse

I am trying to make a request to Googles API.  But I am getting an error with `GetResponse()`.  The error I am getting is...

`'WebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'GetResponse'...`

Visual Studio gives me the option to replace that with `BeginGetResponse()`, but I am not sure how to format the code or change what I already have to accomplish this.  Can anyone point me in the right to direction to resolve this?  It is possible I am missing some assemblies... but I don't think I am.

```
private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {    
      var address = addressInput.Text;
      var requestUri = string.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={0}&sensor=false", Uri.EscapeDataString(address));

      MessageBox.Show(requestUri.ToString());


      var request = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
      var response = request.GetResponse();
      var xdoc = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());    

      var result = xdoc.Element("GeocodeResponse").Element("result");
      var locationElement = result.Element("geometry").Element("location");
      var lat = locationElement.Element("lat");
      var lng = locationElement.Element("lng");
}
```

Comment: try casting it, (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

Comment: I tried that and GetResponse() is still not compatible.

Comment: what kind of application are you writing?

Comment: depending on what version of the framework you are linking against, it could be `GetResponseAsync`.

Comment: Maybe System.Net Version doesn't use GetResponse()... idk.

Comment: i mean is it wpf, mobile, windows universal, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132508/discussion-between-daniel-a-white-and-jedi-nerd).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the asynchronous version like this:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
request.BeginGetResponse(this.FinishWebRequest, request);
```

and then have the `FinishWebRequest` method which will be invoked once the remote server sends the response:

```
private void FinishWebRequest(IAsyncResult result)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
    using (var response = request.EndGetResponse(result))
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        var xdoc = XDocument.Load(responseStream);
        ...
    }
}
```

or if you prefer using an anonymous method:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
request.BeginGetResponse(result => 
{
    using (var response = request.EndGetResponse(result))
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        var xdoc = XDocument.Load(responseStream);
        ...
    }
}, null);
```

Comment: Don't I need to have a `BeginGetResponseStream` method?

Comment: Yes, you do need, as shown in my example: `response.BeginGetResponseStream(this.FinishGetResponseStream, response);`. After getting the response object in the `FinishWebRequest` callback, the next thing you do is `BeginGetResponseStream` on it to be able to fetch the final `Stream` object in the `FinishGetResponseStream` callback.

Comment: Can you give some hints? Compile-time error? Run-time error? Something else?

Comment: Compile-time error: `BeginGetResponseStream` and `EndGetResponseStream` are throwing the same error that GetResponse() was at the beginning... `WebResponse does not contain a definition for BeginGetResponseStream` and throw the same for `EndGetResponseStream`.

Comment: OK, my bad, see my updated answer. Apparently there are no BeginGetResponseStream/EndGetResponseStream methods which simplifies the code further.

Comment: Add if I wanted to check the response or result I could do something like `MessageBox.Show(response.ToString());` after `var xdoc = XDocument.Load(responseStream);`... right? Or maybe response needs to be xdoc?

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(xdoc.ToString());` or just put a breakpoint and inspect the value.